# Can the Sum of Two Tensor Products Be Written as a Single Tensor Product?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

In general, if I have $|\Psi\rangle = (|\Psi_{1_1}\rangle \otimes |\Psi_{1_2}\rangle + |\Psi_{2_1}\rangle \otimes |\Psi_{2_2}\rangle)$,  can I find $|\Psi_{3_1}\rangle$ and $|\Psi_{3_2}\rangle$, such that $|\Psi\rangle = |\Psi_{3_1}\rangle \otimes |\Psi_{3_2}\rangle$? Here $\otimes$ means tensor product and $|\Psi\rangle$ and means a vector. No assumption is made about any relationship between the $|\Psi_{i_j}\rangle$, except that they are all the same dimension and their components are complex numbers.

The motivation is the quantum double slit experiment, where the wave state, $|\Psi\rangle$, between the slits and the detector, is the sum of two interfering waves, and $|\Psi\rangle$ is still in a "pure state", which means that $|\Psi\rangle$ can also be written as a tensor product

Answer (score 10):

In general the answer is no and you can clearly see why when you look at the dimensions: $\dim (V\otimes W)$ is much larger than $\dim (V\times W)$ whenever $V$ and $W$ are both of dimension greater than $1$. This tells you that in general a tensor is more than just a couple of vectors.

Tensors of the form $a\otimes b$ are called *pure tensors*.

---

Edit: As was correctly noted in the comments, the dimensional observation does not provide a proof just by itself, it is rather a convenient way to remember this fact. If $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is a basis of $W$ then a basis of $V\otimes W$ is given by $\{e_i\otimes f_j\}$ (dimension $nm$) and an element of $V\otimes W$ can be represented by an $n\times m$ matrix where the entries are coordinates in that basis. Now with this description, pure tensors are matrices of rank $1$. Except when $\dim V$ or $\dim W$ is equal to $1$, not all matrices have rank $1$.

The subset of pure tensors is not a subspace, however, so in a way the dimensional observation might be misleading.

Comment: If $|\Psi\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
           a_1 \\
           a_2 \\
           a_3 \\
           a_4
         \end{bmatrix}$ and $a_i \neq 0$, then I think I can do what I am asking to do in my question. I think that would apply no matter what the dimension of $|\Psi\rangle$ is. Is that true?

Comment: @David I am not sure I understand your notation, here $\left|\Psi\right\rangle$ seems to be one vector. How do you see it as a tensor?

Comment: If every tensor was indeed a pure tensor, why would it follow that the dimension of $V\otimes W$ is not larger than that of $V\times W$? In other words, does your answer lead to a real proof?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the injection you mention wouldn't necessarily be linear

Comment: I like your edit. Sorry for being nitpicking, I really couldn't think of an easy way to prove this besides resorting to matrices, and I was curious if you had something else in mind

Comment: @Bananach Don't be sorry, on the contrary one should always complain when a post is confusing. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 9):

The matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& 0& 0\\ 0&0& 0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is a sum of two simple tensors which is not a simple tensor itself. In particular, $A=E_{11}\otimes E_{11}+E_{22}\otimes E_{22}$ where $E_{11}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $E_{22}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. In fact, this is one of the strengths of quantum science: not all quantum states are pure states. In linear algebra terms, not all tensors are simple tensors.

Comment: Can you easily prove that $A$ is not a simple tensor?

Comment: If $A$ where a simple tensor $C\otimes D$, then it should look like $\begin{pmatrix} c_{11}D& c_{12}D\\ c_{21}D& c_{22}D\end{pmatrix}$ where $D$ is a 2-by-2 matrix. If you compare the entries, you'll eventually get a contradiction.